# Bootstrap buttons with square corners in IE9

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm really tearing my hair out over this one. I'm trying to make a fairly simple page with a little bit of text, two radio buttons and a submit button. So far it looks fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE9 the submit button has square corners:

[image: IE9 submit button issue]

When I look at the example pages on the Bootstrap website the corners of the buttons are all properly rounded, so it must be something I'm doing rather than an issue with IE. I just can't figure out what.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>The welcome page.</h1>
        <p>Welcome to our page. Please select one of the options below and press 'Submit'.</p>
        <form>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="radio">
                <input checked="" id="1-1" name="1" value="opt1" type="radio">
                    <label for="opt1">Option 1</label>
                <input id="1-2" name="1" value="opt2" type="radio">
                    <label for="opt2">Option 2</label>
            </div>
            </div>
          <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Submit" type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a demo: http://bootply.com/78669

**UPDATE:** This might help to narrow it down. When I load the page from a new location in IE9, the submit button looks the way it should:

[image: Button rendering properly]

...but I get the 'IE restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls' message. If I click to allow blocked content, that's when the button corners go square.

Comment: As a quick fix you can use this: http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: Are you running IE 9 in standards mode or have it set to emulated IE 8 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following commenter Ryan McDonough's advice, I went through the file and stripped out as much css as I could, and found the problem. Which was:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Remove the link to bootstrap-theme, and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer (under version 9) does not natively support rounded corners.

There's an amazing script that will magically add it for you: CSS3 PIE. Hopw you will figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The issue will lay in your IE 9 settings, I'm currently running IE 9 and the corners are rounded. Make sure to check your developer options (F12) and see if you are running in

```
BROWSER MODE: IE 9 and DOCUMENT MODE: IE9 STANDARDS
```

[Find a screenshot showing these options at the top right here.](http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/fig6.png)

Comment: The document mode was set to 'quirks' but unfortunately setting it to IE9 standards hasn't solved the problem. I can only think it must be something to do with internet/intranet security settings.

Comment: Can't be anything to do with those, it's just CSS, try removing any styles you've added e.g that btn-lg as that's not native bootstrap.

Comment: They've changed the name of btn-large to btn-lg for version 3. I tried going through and removing as much css as possible, and the problem seems to be that I was linking to bootstrap-theme.css. Remove that link and everything works as it should. Thank you!

Comment: @patabongo glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer (under version 9) does not natively support rounded corners.

There's an amazing script that will magically add it for you: http://css3pie.com .Hope you will figure out the rest.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the script. IE user's are NOT going to stop using your site over a few square corners. Move on and get your site finished.

Comment: The confusing thing is, I'm using version 9! I've added an update to the question with more information.

Comment: You're probably right marflar, but on a site this simple I worry when I can't get one of the elements to display properly.

Comment: Question says he's running IE 9.